# DotNetOpenAuth Google openid certificate trouble

Tags: c#, openid, certificate, dotnetopenauth

I am using dotnetopenauth to authenticate user via openid. This works fine for people who have 'standard' providers like myid.net or myopenid.com

However, when a person uses the google openid url for authentication, things get weird. They can log in just fine, but when they log out and try to log in again, an exception occurs that says it' can't find the endpoint.

A closer look at the logs reveals this:

```
An operation failed because the following certificate has validation errors:\n\nSubject Name: CN=www.google.com, O=Google Inc, L=Mountain View, S=California, C=US\nIssuer Name: CN=Thawte SGC CA, O=Thawte Consulting (Pty) Ltd., C=ZA\nThumbprint: C1956DC8A7DFB2A5A56934DA09778E3A11023358\n\nErrors:\n\n The root of the certificate chain is not a trusted root authority..
```

After half an hour or so, it will work again.

Any ideas of how to fix it?

Comment: Is this *per* Google user (can 3 google users log in consecutively) or does one google user break it for the next 30 minutes for everyone?

Comment: It doesn't matter who tries to login; the login page fails to connect to the google url after the first try, so noone else can log in. It's as if it accepts the certificate the first time, then rejects it the consecutive times. As a temporary fix I added the Google certificates manually. This prevents the error but obviously I'm not supposed to install certificates for individual providers. Who knows what other providers will also fail.

Comment: Really quite bizarre.  Sorry I can't offer any other ideas.  Never seen this before.